# Need to show out.println command data in table format

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

Please help me out where i am unable to show the below "**out.println"** data in table format.

```
if(rs.next())          
 {         
out.println(rs.getString("Case_Title"));         
out.println(rs.getString("Problem_Descr"));          
out.println(rs.getString("Problem_Submit"));         
}         
}        
catch(Exception e)        
{         
e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
http://www.coderanch.com/t/493812/JSP/java/display-records-Grid-view-format

All you need to do is use jsp scriptlet <% .....%>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<%
    while (rs.next()) {
%>
<p ><%=rs.getString("Case_Title")%></p>
<p ><%=rs.getString("Problem_Descr")%></p>
<p ><%=rs.getString("Problem_Submit")%></p>

<%
    }
%>
```

and  [avoid scriplets](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2010/07/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files.html),if possible

Comment: @badshah..its not working getting the error after applying the following code

Answer (score 0):

Use below code::

```
<table>
    if(rs.next())          
    {         
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(rs.getString("Case_Title"));         
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(rs.getString("Problem_Descr"));          
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println(rs.getString("Problem_Submit"));         
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }         
    }        
    catch(Exception e)        
    {         
        e.printStackTrace();        
    } 
<table>
```